# Get git-pane in RSTUDIO to show for new user in existing git-R-project (Windows) local repository

Tags: git, rstudio

I have a existing R-project, git activated and working. We're adding a new developer to the project who can't get the git-pane to show up in Rstudio.

The developer can create new projects with git activated and usable for other users. So Rstudio have no problem finding git as is.

Is there a bash command to force Rstudio to recognize it as a git-project or how do we get git to register for my colleague?

**.gitignore:**

```
.Rproj.user
.Rhistory
.RData
.Ruserdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the `project_name.Rproj` exists on the new collaborator's machine? It might have been accidentally added to `.gitignore`

Comment: Certain, no, but it's not in the .gitignore-file and the location is one a fileserver. 

.gitignore:
.Rproj.user
.Rhistory
.RData
.Ruserdata